# Article does not enumerate citations

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, citing, natbib

eventhough I am loading the "\usepackage[sort, numbers]{natbib}", my bibliography does not get enumerated, while using BibTeX.
Please check out the code from my .tex:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sort, numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\input{setup/packages.tex}

\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength\headheight{0pt} 
\begin{center}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.65\linewidth]{images/fu_logo.png}            
\end{center}    



Matriculation Number:  \\
E-Mail:  \\
Course of Studies: BSc Physics \\
Supervisor:  \\
\par
\vspace{1.5cm}
\large
\date{\today{}, Berlin}

\end{center}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents




\pagebreak








\section*{Abstract}
Present thesis abstract here, typically there are no references, figures or tables in the abstract.
\pagebreak




\section{Introduction}
bla bla bla (\cite{billi2013cyanobacteria})
yoyo (\cite{billi2019dried})
\subsection{Subsection Example}
I am a subsection
\subsubsection{Sub Subsection Example}
I am a sub subsection
\pagebreak









\section{Methods and Materials}
\pagebreak



\section{Results}


\pagebreak





\section{Discussion}
\pagebreak


\section{Conclusions}
\pagebreak
\section*{Acknowledgements}
Personal acknowledgements and/or dedications may be included by the candidate directly after the declaration page. Where possible these should be kept to one page and be of a tone appropriate to a higher degree.
\pagebreak
\section*{Declaration}
I hereby certify that the material, which I now submit for assessment on the programmes of study leading to the award of Bachelor of Science, is entirely my own work and has not been taken from the work of others except to the extent that such work has been cited and acknowledged within the text of my own work. No portion of the work contained in this thesis has been submitted in support of an application for another degree or qualification to this or any other institution.

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{flushright}
-----------------------------------\\
Maximilian \\
\today
\end{flushright}
\pagebreak
%\section{Appendices}
%\pagebreak


%prints bibliography from bibliography file.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and this is my .bib code:

```
@article{billi2013cyanobacteria,
  title={Cyanobacteria from extreme deserts to space},
  author={Billi, Daniela and Baque, Mickael and Smith, H and McKay, C},
  year={2013},
  publisher={US}
}


@article{billi2019dried,
  title={Dried biofilms of desert strains of Chroococcidiopsis survived prolonged exposure to space and Mars-like conditions in low Earth orbit},
  author={Billi, Daniela and Staibano, Clelia and Verseux, Cyprien and Fagliarone, Claudia and Mosca, Claudia and Baqu{\'e}, Mickael and Rabbow, Elke and Rettberg, Petra},
  journal={Astrobiology},
  volume={19},
  number={8},
  pages={1008--1017},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Mary Ann Liebert, Inc., publishers 140 Huguenot Street, 3rd Floor New~…}
}





@article{Quille2019,
author = {Quille, Keith and Bergin, Susan},
doi = {10.1080/08993408.2019.1612679},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/keith/OneDrive/Mendelay/Quille, Bergin, Quille - 2019 - CS1 how will they do How can we help A decade of research and practice research and practice.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0899-3408},
journal = {Computer Science Education},
keywords = {CS1,Introductory programming,artificial neural networks,attrition rates,growth mindset,interventions,machine learning,predicting programming performance,programming performance,programming self-efficacy},
mendeley-groups = {Keith Quille Publications},
number = {2-3},
pages = {254--282},
publisher = {Routledge},
title = {{CS1 : how will they do ? How can we help ? A decade of research and practice research and practice}},
url = {https://doi.org/10.1080/08993408.2019.1612679},
volume = {29},
year = {2019}
}


@inproceedings{Quille:Gender,
    author          = {Quille, Keith and Culligan, Natalie and Bergin, Susan},
    title           = {Insights on Gender Differences in CS1: A Multi-institutional, Multi-variate Study.},
    booktitle       = {Proceedings of the 2017 ACM Conference on Innovation and Technology in Computer Science Education},
    series          = {ITiCSE '17},
    year            = {2017},
    isbn            = {978-1-4503-4704-4},
    location        = {Bologna, Italy},
    pages           = {263--268},
    numpages        = {6},
    url             = {http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/3059009.3059048},
    doi             = {10.1145/3059009.3059048},
    acmid           = {3059048},
    publisher       = {ACM},
    address         = {New York, NY, USA},
    keywords        = {computer science education, cs1., female, gender, programming, programming self-efficacy},
}
```

Comment: Do not understand the command ```\printbibliography```. Instead you can load your ```.bib``` file using ```\bibliography{sample.bib}``` and compile.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your document setup isn't entirely clear. On the one hand, the preamble features the instructions `\usepackage[sort, numbers]{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`. On the other hand, the body of the document features `\printbibliography`, which is a command provided by the `biblatex` package Iwhich you don't load). What happens if you replace `\printbibliography` with `\bibliography{mybib}`, where `mybib.bib` is the name of the bib file, and if you run a full recompile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more?

Comment: From the code we can see so far (`\usepackage[sort, numbers]{natbib} \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`) you are using `natbib` (a BibTeX-based solution), where `\printbibliography` is not defined and will not do anything useful (`\printbibliography` is defined by `biblatex`). Remove `\printbibliography` and replace it with `\bibliography{<bib file>}` where `<bib file>` is the file name of your `.bib` file, but *without* the `.bib` file extension (so `\bibliography{refs}` if your `.bib` file is called `refs.bib`).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you guys for the quick answers. You were right, I mixed up the packages. I used a template which was hiding a lot of `/usepackackage` commands behind a link (via `/input` command) to another .tex file in the project folder, which I did not even notice. There, the package biblatex was being used. I just removed that one and used the `\bibliography` command instead of `\printbibliography`